# Install Windows Subsystem for Linux in Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

I am wondering how to install Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on Windows 10 machine. I have only one hard drive in my laptop. Can I install WSL on the external 500 GB hard drive having USB interface ?

Would it be Ubuntu or any other version of Linux ? Can I also install PetaLinux as well in the WSL for Xilinx boards ?

Answer (score 1):

You install WSL Ubuntu from the [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-2004-lts/9n6svws3rx71?).

Try installing it anywhere you like on your Windows system.

"Any other version of Linux" is a Microsoft decision, not us.