# My question is about Ubuntu on windows

Tags: downloads, system

After the initial installation of Ubuntu for Windows from Microsoft the store I discovered that it wasn't downloaded to my PC but installed directly by Microsoft on my computer. Which means all the download files are not found on my PC. What can I do?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *installed direct on Microsoft*?

Comment: You can search the Microsoft download sites and see if it is there. This is an off topic question for this site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Windows Subsystem for Linux in Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1290254/install-windows-subsystem-for-linux-in-windows-10)